# Inno Setup - Create shortcut in "Send to" context menu

Tags: windows, inno-setup

How can I create a link to my program in the "Send to" folder using Inno Setup, so that it is shown in the "Send to" context menu in Windows Explorer?

There is already a [directory constant](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) for the "Send to" folder, but how can I create a link there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As any other shortcut, using an entry in the [`[Icons]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{usersendto}\My Prog"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```

---

*The `{sendto}` constant has been renamed to `{usersendto}` in Inno Setup 5.6.1.*

Answer (score 2):

For me, following worked:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{usersendto}\My Prog"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
```